# How can we justify setting the affinity $\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i$ equal to zero at chemical equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Let $\sum_A \nu_A A \rightarrow \sum_B \nu_B B$ be a general reaction whose progress during time interval $dt$ is measured by $d\zeta$, so the amount of reactants consumed and products generated in mole would be $d N_i=\nu_i d\zeta$, wherein, $\nu_i$ would take negative values for the reactants being consumed.

From on the other hand we already know from the second law of thermodynamics that the reaction will occur in the direction in which $\sum_i \mu_i dN_i \le 0$, wherein, $\mu_i=\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_i}\bigr|_{p,T,N_j\;(j\ne i)}$ are the chemical potentials, so that we would have:
$$\left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right)\; d\zeta \le 0$$
The equality implies reversibility and should denote the equilibrium (*am I right?*). At the equilibrium it is clear that the progression of the reaction should vanish and we should have $d\zeta=0$, so that the term $\left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right)$ should be free to gain any positive, zero or negative finite value. However, this is not what Guggenheim has written in his Thermodynamics book. He has first assumed in a given direction the reaction progresses, so that in that direction $d\zeta>0$, then has canceled out this positive quantity from the inequality and achieved: $\left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right) \le 0$, and eventually concluded that at the equilibrium the equality holds and we should have $\left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right) = 0$.

But how is it justified to be true when we already know at the equilibrium $d\zeta>0$ doesn\t hold and we should instead write: $d\zeta=0$?

Thanks for bearing with me, I'm new to chemistry.

Comment: please specify what is $\mu_i$

Comment: @Aditya, their formal definition has been added.

Comment: Ad 1. Haven't you forgot to add a mixing entropy term? Ad 2. Maybe I misunderstand you, but I think your problem is that: It is a standard method to find a stable equilibrium point saying that the first derivative of the enthalpy etc. is zero, but even when the systems suffers a perturbation, it returns to the equilibirum. I.e. even for small, non-zero dζ the system stays in equilibrium which can only happen if  (∑iμiνi)=0.

Comment: @Greg, about the mixing entropy I'm not sure I have understood what you mean (sorry I'm new to chemistry), but the inequality mentioned is indeed derived from $dG\le 0$ at constant pressure and temperature. Actually I saw another book and yet the same reasoning was mentioned there, that $d\zeta$ is considered positive and so on. Hence, it seems no term has been forgotten here as the formulation is not mine.

Comment: @Greg, about your second point maybe you are right, I cannot judge it very easily at this point, but what you say seems more precisely addressing the question if the equilibrium achieved is a stable equilibrium. By the way, at the very equilibrium no advancement is expectable and thus we should have $d\zeta=0$. Maybe the authors are implicitly assuming that the equilibrium should also be stable, so that the term $\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i$ should be finite and preferably small, but zero is somewhat a lot idealization, or perhaps I am still wrong?

Comment: @Greg, sorry I was wrong, before equilibrium is achieved we have $d\zeta\ge 0$ and past the equilibrium point $d\zeta\le 0$, therefore, the greater be the term $\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i$ the more stable would be the equilibrium, unless it also changes in sign and honestly I don't know anything about its behavior!?

Comment: @topology I've tried giving this more of a descriptive title, but I haven't studied this stuff for *[a long while]*, so please make any corrections to it as necessary.

Comment: @topology This equilibrium is a stable one, and from chemical experience / intuition we know that the system is going toward the equilibrium from both directions. The  dζ=0 condition is just not enough to describe the system, any combination of chemical potential can satisfy it. I think it is easier to re-order your arguments: at a given ∑iμiνi we can determine the sign of dζ, i.e. which direction the system progress. If ∑iμiνi is non-zero then there is always a dζ, which satisfies dG < 0, i.e. the reaction will minimize G. You need a vanishing  ∑iμiνi, so no dζ can further decrease G.

Comment: @jonsca, thanks for caring, I felt the question was not around setting $d\zeta$ equal to zero but about justification of $\sum \mu_i\nu_i=0$, so changed the title again, but meanwhile if you have been far from the stuff for a long time but I have never been involved in this sort of stuffs, so yet you will know better anyway.

Comment: @Greg, you are totally right that as stated in my question "any combination of chemical potential can satisfy it", which cannot be correct. So let me write $dG|_{p,T}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial\zeta} d\zeta$ and equilibrium would then be defined by $\frac{\partial G}{\partial\zeta}=0$ and not $d\zeta=0$. Thank you very much for your inspiring comments, you can prepare them as a complete answer and God-willing I'll accept it.

Comment: @Greg Would you condense your comments into an answer? Otherwise, if you don't have the time I could formulate an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chemical equilibrium is a stable equilibrium, i.e. the system returns to equilibrium to whatever perturbations. This also leads to the condition of equilibrium, as it should  contain this information.

**The short answer to your question:**

Due to the stability, the system stays/returns to equilibrium at any kind of small perturbation. It also means, $\left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right)\; d\zeta = 0$ not only in the equilibrium point, but also for any small $d\zeta$. Therefore the $\left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right)$ itself must be zero.

**Somewhat longer answer:**

The reaction goes from one direction to the other ($\sum_A \nu_A A \rightarrow \sum_B \nu_B B$)  spontaneously only till it reaches the equilibrium condition. In this direction  $\sum_i \mu_i dN_i \le 0$.

We followed the reaction from a given concentration toward equilibrium. If we follow the same $\sum_A \nu_A A \rightarrow \sum_B \nu_B B$  transformation BEYOND the equilibrium point, $ \sum_i \mu_i dN_i $ must change sign at the equilibrium point, and it must be positive should be valid (since it is not a spontaneous reaction).

Therefore the condition of equilibrium is not $d\zeta = 0 $ , but sign change: $ \sum_i \mu_i dN_i =0$.